# SQL dynamically pivot and group results

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I have a table set up like below:

```
CLIENTNAME          MONTHANDYEAR     RESOURCE     COST
abc                 JAN2011          res1         1000
abc                 FEB2011          res1         2000
def                 JAN2011          res2         1500
def                 MAR2011          res1         2000 
ghi                 MAR2011          res3         2500
```

I need an output like below.  Months are to be generated dynamically in 3-month intervals.  In this case, is there a way to pivot by MONTHANDYEAR as well as group by clientname?

```
RESOURCE    CLIENTNAME     JAN2011      FEB2011      MAR2011   
res1        abc            1000         1000
res1        def                                      2000
res2        def            1500
res3        ghi                                      2500
```

Comment: How much of this *has* to be done on the database end? For example can you build your query in the client application? Or are you using a reporting solution which could do the pivot/grouping?

Comment: Our reporting software has very limited features and cannot transpose data like above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the PIVOT operator is for:

```
SELECT 
  Resource, ClientName,
  [JAN2011], [FEB2011], [MAR2011]
FROM
  (
  SELECT 
    *  
  FROM tblname
  ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
  (
  SUM(COST)
  FOR MONTHANDYEAR IN ([JAN2011], [FEB2011], [MAR2011])
  ) AS PivotTable;
```

Since your months are selected dynamically using @startDate as a base month, you can use the following dynamic query:

```
DECLARE @startDate datetime
SET @startDate = '2011-01-01'

DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX)
SET @sql = 'SELECT
        Resource, ClientName, [' +
          REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, @startDate, 13), 4, 8), ' ', '') + '], [' +
          REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @startDate), 13), 4, 8), ' ', '') + '], [' +
          REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, 2, @startDate), 13), 4, 8), ' ', '') + ']
        FROM
          (
          SELECT
            *
          FROM tblName
          ) AS SourceTable
        PIVOT
          (
          SUM(COST)
          FOR MONTHANDYEAR IN (' +
                  QUOTENAME(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, @startDate, 13), 4, 8), ' ', '')) + ', ' +
                  QUOTENAME(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @startDate), 13), 4, 8), ' ', '')) + ', ' +
                  QUOTENAME(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, 2, @startDate), 13), 4, 8), ' ', '')) + ')
          ) AS PivotTable'

execute(@sql)
```

working [sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/650a8/3)

Answer (score 1):

This data transformation can be done with the `PIVOT` function.

If you know the values, then you can hard-code the `monthandyear` dates:

```
select resource,
  clientname,
  isnull(jan2011, '') Jan2011,
  isnull(feb2011, '') Feb2011,
  isnull(mar2011, '') Mar2011
from
(
  select clientname, monthandyear, resource, cost
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  sum(cost)
  for monthandyear in (Jan2011, Feb2011, Mar2011)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3e06/1).

But if the dates are unknown, then you will need to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(monthandyear) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colNames = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', isnull(' + QUOTENAME(monthandyear)+', 0) as '+QUOTENAME(monthandyear)
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT resource, clientname,' + @colNames + ' from 
             (
                select clientname, monthandyear, resource, cost
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(cost)
                for monthandyear in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/830f4/6).

The result of both is:

```
| RESOURCE | CLIENTNAME | JAN2011 | FEB2011 | MAR2011 |
-------------------------------------------------------
|     res1 |        abc |    1000 |    2000 |       0 |
|     res1 |        def |       0 |       0 |    2000 |
|     res2 |        def |    1500 |       0 |       0 |
|     res3 |        ghi |       0 |       0 |    2500 |
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I wish i could give you the checkmark as well, but PinnyM's answer worked a bit better for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Resource, Clientname
, SUM(CASE WHEN MonthAndYear = 'JAN2011' THEN COST ELSE 0 END) AS JAN2011
, SUM(CASE WHEN MonthAndYear = 'FEB2011' THEN COST ELSE 0 END) AS FEB2011
, SUM(CASE WHEN MonthAndYear = 'MAR2011' THEN COST ELSE 0 END) AS MAR2011
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Resource, Clientname
```

You can also remove the `ELSE 0` to return a `NULL` value for resource/clientname combinations without data

Comment: Thanks for this, but i should have added that the months need to be generated dynamically, three months at a time.

Comment: @0onetwo, can you pass these month names as parameters, or a single parameter comma delimited list?

Comment: A starting month will be passed in as a parameter, and the query will do the calculations for that month and the next two.